# Apache Camel redelivery: how to use the attempt number

Tags: java, logging, apache-camel

I have a Camel Route with the onException clause: at each redelivery I want to increase the redeliveryDelay. How do I get the attemptNumber?
The DefaultErrorHandler clearly stores it somewhere because it prints it in the log e.g. "On delivery attempt: 1 caught"

```
onException(MyException.class)
    .handled(true)
    .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, "Exception. Retry in " + (10000 * attemptNumber) + " ms")
    .maximumRedeliveries(2)
    .redeliveryDelay(10000 * attemptNumber)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried reading in the header value stored for [Exchange's `REDELIVERY_COUNTER`](https://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/Exchange.html#REDELIVERY_COUNTER)? You might also use `exponentialBackoff` and `backoffMultiplier` to increase the duration of redelivery attempts. You might also want to read http://camel.apache.org/dead-letter-channel.html

Comment: Thank you Roman!

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to define re-delivery delay time. You can do this with the second method.

First using fixed amount of time using `redeliveryDelay` and a long number to show how many milliseconds the delay would be:

```
onException(MyException.class) 
    .maximumRedeliveries(20)
    .redeliveryDelay(1000)
```

that means delays for attempts are 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, etc.

Second using `backOffMultiplier` and a double number that multiplies to the `RedeliveryDelay` time for each consequent delay

```
onException(MyException.class) 
    .maximumRedeliveries(20)
    .redeliveryDelay(1000)
    .backOffMultiplier(2)
```

that means delays for attempts are 1000, 2000, 4000, 8000, etc.

Third is using `delayPattern` and a string pattern for delays like:

```
onException(MyException.class) 
    .maximumRedeliveries(20)
    .redeliveryDelay()
    .delayPattern("5:1000;10:2000")
```

for this pattern the attempts 0 to 4 is happening immediately, 5 to 9 after 1000 milliseconds and 10 to `maximumRedeliveries` happens after 2000 milliseconds.